# Why doesn't my key binding work?

Tags: key-bindings, vertico

I tried adding this code to interactively clear the echo area (or mini-buffer not sure??) during Vertico's find-file.

```lisp
(defun my-kill-line ()
  "Remove text from the echo area by killing backwards"
  (interactive)
  (kill-line 0))

(keymap-set vertico-map "C-M-g" 'my-kill-line)
```

Emacs 29.1 says `C-M-g` undefined when I try to use it.

I put both expressions in `vertico.el` near the top and ran `M-x eval-buffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that some code in `vertico.el` reset the value of `vetico-map`. Try to put your code somewhere else, and make sure to load it **after** Vertico. Alternatively, add your key binding to `minibuffer-mode-map` to make sure Vertico does not erase it.

To answer your other question, you are dealing with the mini buffer.

Comment: This worked thanks. Moved the code to my .emacs, just after the use-package entry for vertico, and it works as expected.